# cin.get() in string class or overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, overloading

I have a string class at the below:

```
class Mystring
{
        private:
            char *letter;

        public:

            friend ostream & operator <<(ostream  &out, const Mystring& s);
            friend istream & operator >>(istream &in,Mystring& s);
};
```

this is in the main function:

```
int main()
{
    Mystring s[10];

    cin.get(s,10);
    cout << s;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

when i use cin.get i get error like this

> Error 1   error C2664: 'std::basic_istream>
>   &std::basic_istream>::get(std::basic_streambuf>
>   &,_Elem)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'Mystring' to 'char
>   *'    c:\users\thai\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\overloading\overloading\main.cpp    11  1   Overloading

i think i should create an overloading for `cin.get()` , but how ??

Comment: Why are you not using your `>>` operator?

Answer (score 1):

`cin.get` is a member function of `cin` (hence the `.`). You can't overload it, so you should use your `>>` operator.

```
for (auto& i : s)
    cin >> s;
```

If you don't want that, just write a `get` method in your `MyString` that takes an `istream`.

```
Mystring& Mystring::get(std::istream& in) { ... }

Mystring ms;
ms.get(std::cin);
```

You can't overload a member function of another class outside of that class. You can do that for operators because of their syntax, but that's it. You'll have to change your own class to handle it.

Comment: OMG!!! If i use my >> operator it will be deleted all characters, which are after space :(

Comment: @BunThaiDeng And that's now what `get` is going to do?

Comment: when i input a string like that "Hello" then i output it will be "Hello" but when i input "Hello World" it output "Hello " ,so i need to use cin.get();

Comment: @BunThaiDeng The question was how to overload `cin.get`, and the answer is it isn't possible. I can't tell what you're trying to do, but if you're having a problem implementing something, you can ask a question containing all the relevant information about it.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning it to an array of MyString, You should give it to MyString object instead.

Provided you have implementation for ">>" and "<<" implementation correctly, this should work

```
int main()
{
   Mystring s;

   // Mystring should construct memory for *letter and put the string      in it
   // Quite confusing why you want to have only one letter inside MyString, 
   // Probably you need to change to a better name *letters.
   cin >> s;  // will stop reading till white space
   cout << s;

   //Incase you want to read a char array and construct a MyString
   char a[10];
   cin.get(a,10);
   MyString(a); // You need to define a constructor in MyString for this to work.


    _getch();
    return 0;

}
```